# weird behaviour with single quote escape in irb

Tags: ruby

```
puts 'I am 6\'2" tall'
```

the output is `I am 6'2" tall`

But in irb 
if i types this string `'I am 6\'2" tall'` without `puts`
i got like `"I am 6'2\" tall"`

Note the position of escape character in the output

Why the position of escape character got changed?

Answer (score 1):

You got different types of quote characters escaped within different types of quotes.

- Within single quotes, single quotes need to be escaped to be distinguished from the end of the string, but double quotes need not.
- Within double quotes, single quotes need not be escaped, but double quotes need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Because in `IRB` `'I am 6\'2" tall'.inspect` is happening, which is same as `puts 'I am 6\'2" tall'`

Comment: In my code above original code escape character is before `'` but IRB prints it before `"`.so IRB output is not exactly same as `puts` output.

Comment: IRB is using #inspect, not #to_s.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes. It is thanks for pointing that to me.. very helpful.